# SVN Batch Rename Whitespace Issue

Tags: python, svn, syntax, call

I'm trying to batch rename some files in svn.  I have an issue where some files have a space in them.  when I try to run I get this error:

```
svn: Cannot copy path '00009.png' into its own child '00009.png'
```

my code is:

```
import subprocess.call
call("svn rename " + "test 00009.png" + " test1 00009.png")
```

looks like it's splitting at the whitespace.  any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
call("svn rename " + "\"test 00009.png\"" + " \"test1 00009.png\"")
```

Basically surrounding all the paths with quotes, which you can easily do with say something like

```
"\"%s\"" % file
```

Answer (score 2):

Backslash escape your whitespace.

So:

```
import subprocess.call
call("svn rename " + r"test\ 00009.png" + r" test1\ 00009.png")
```

The `r''` syntax means that python should treat the `\`s literally, not as escapes in themselves.  It passes them through svn where they are treated as escapes.

Comment: essentially I'll need a method to str replace the whitespaces?  Cause i'ma be batching this on 100 files.

Comment: yeah.  is there whitespace besides spaces?  because if not you could just do `filename = filename.replace(' ', r'\ ')`.  If so a regex would work.  Unless I'm missing something.